# Query Regarding PIG- How to put a if like condition in ForEach

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a query wrt writing pig script

```
 RESULT_SOMETYPE = FOREACH SOMETYPE_DATA_GROUPED  GENERATE flatten(group) , SUM(SOMETYPEDATA.DURATION) as duration, COUNT(SOMETYPEDATA.DURATION) as cnt;
```

Here I want to replace **SUM(SOMETYPEDATA.DURATION)** with some number like

```
if(0>Sum > 1000) then put 1
if(1001> Sum > 2000 )  then put 2
if(2001> Sum > 3000 )  then put 3
```

How to acheive this in pig

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

`SPLIT` will do that but not inside the `FOREACH` loop. Pig also has a [ternary](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators+and+More) operator kind of thing but that will not be helpful to store the result in a variable. Here is how you can use SPLIT to achieve something close to your requirement.

```
A = LOAD '/home/vignesh/a.dat' using PigStorage(',') as (a:int,b:int,c:int);
SPLIT A INTO B IF (a > 0 AND a < 1000),  C IF (a > 1001 AND a<2000), D IF (a > 2001 AND a < 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use either bincond operator (?:) or CASE statement (from Pig Version : 0.12 on wards) to achieve the objective.

```
RESULT_SOMETYPE = FOREACH SOMETYPE_DATA_GROUPED  GENERATE flatten(group) AS grp_name , SUM(SOMETYPEDATA.DURATION) as duration_sum, COUNT(SOMETYPEDATA.DURATION) as cnt;

result_required = FOREACH RESULT_SOMETYPE GENEATE grp_name, 
                        (duration_sum > 0 AND duration_sum < 1000 ? 1 : 
                                        (duration_sum > 1001 AND duration_sum < 2000 ? 2 : 
                                                (duration_sum > 2001 AND duration_sum < 3000 ? 3 : 9999)     
                                        )
                         ) AS duration, cnt;
```

Refer : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#arithmetic

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and come back.!